# CloudPageURL redirect doesn't work in individual email test send

Tags: marketing-cloud

I do know that resources online are saying to put the CloudPagesURL inside RedirectTo like this "%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(4508))=%%". Which is what I have.

However, when testing with a single email address in the Preview and Test tab, the email will ultimately have the link point to "%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(4508))=%%" and not do the logic to actually convert it to the Cloud Page URL.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself some headache and use a Data Extension with one record with the email in it instead.
Then use the TEST DATA EXTENSION option instead of the INDIVIDUALS tab and select that data extension.

*Couldn't find anything that mentioned this phenomenon online so hopefully this helps someone. You are not alone.*